# Twitter Analytics does not match our count

Tags: twitter

I have my own custom url shortener that I use when posting on Twitter. My custom url shortener logs the view count. My problem is that as soon as I post a custom shortened url on Twitter my count instantaneously jumps up to around 30 clicks but the Twitter Analytics still shows 0.

Has anyone seen this? I have a feeling that Twitter is verifying my url.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why my analytics does not match is once you post a tweet, the url gets scanned by bots.

I noticed that I also didn't have a robots.txt file.  I created robots.txt to my root and added the following code:

```
#Code to not allow any search engines!
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Related issue:
[How can I block all bots from crawling my twitter link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436087/how-can-i-block-all-bots-from-crawling-my-twitter-link)